# N-curses within Python : how to catch and print non ascii character?

Tags: python, unicode, ncurses, non-ascii-characters, python-curses

I want to make a small program with ncurses/python and to be able to use/type in french and japanese. I understand that I should set the locale and use unicode standard.

But how to deal with the result from screen.getch() ? I would like to display the typed character within the ncurses window regardless of the language.

I understand that some unicode conversion is necessary but can't find what to do (and i've searched quite a bit : this character conversion bussiness isnt easy to understand for amateurs).

Additional question : it seems that for non ascii characters we must used addstr() instead of addch(). Similarly should I use getstr() instead of getch() ?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import curses
from curses import wrapper
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def main(scr):
    # Following lines are some sort of "proof of concept"
    # Indeed it print latin or japanese characters allright
    scr.addstr(0, 0, u'\u3042'.encode('utf-8')) # print あ
    scr.addstr(1, 0, 'é'.encode('utf-8'))       # print é

    # But here I would like to type in a character and have it displayed onscreen
    while (True):
        car = scr.getch()
        if car == 27: # = Escape key
            break
        else:
        # What should I put between those parenthesis to
        # print the typed character on the third line of the screen 
            scr.addstr(3, 0, ???? )

wrapper(main)
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Linux or an other Unix-like (not Windows). Can you confirm it, and can you confirm that you do not need Windows compatibility?

Comment: Indeed I am using linux (debian based distribution called bunsen labs) and I do not need windows compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

[`unctrl`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.unctrl) is the function to use, for results from [`getch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch):

> **`curses.unctrl(`*ch*`)`**
>
> Return a string which is a *printable representation* of the character ch. Control characters are displayed as a caret followed by the character, for example as **`^C`**. Printing characters are left as they are.

If you want to read UTF-8 directly, use [`get_wch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.get_wch) (which was not available in the python2 wrapper):

> *window.**get_wch**([y, x])*
>
> Get a wide character. Return a character for most keys, or an integer for function keys, keypad keys, and other special keys. In no-delay mode, raise an exception if there is no input.
>
> New in version ***3.3***.

even with *that*, you still must ensure that the locale is initialized.  The Python documentation assumes that you have access to the ncurses documentation:

- [*Initialization*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization), in the ncurses manual page
- [get_wch, wget_wch, mvget_wch, mvwget_wch, unget_wch](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html)- get (or push
  back) a wide character from curses terminal keyboard

Comment: Sorry to say  that "é" that should count as a printing character is not left as it is. When printed it becomes M-) . Is there an extra conversion step to this ?

Comment: sure - you have to tell python what the locale is -- otherwise, that character isn't printable in the POSIX (default) locale.

Answer (score 0):

getch/getkey are broken in Python. They are supposed to return a character when encoding is set up as documented, but instead they return octets from a UTF-8 sequence one by one each time the function is called. You need to work around the defect by collecting the octets in a loop until you have a complete sequence. A sequence is complete when it can be successfully decoded, otherwise incomplete.

Compare with the following program which works just fine (run with `perl -C so-56373360.pl`):

```perl
use Term::ReadKey qw(ReadKey ReadMode);
ReadMode 'raw';
while () {
    my $c = ReadKey 0;
    last if $c eq "\e"; # Escape
    print $c;
}
ReadMode 'restore';
```

Comment: Thanks to your comment I started to understand what to look for !

Comment: Indeed with a very small script I could verify that typing "qwer" calls getch() 4 times while typing "bépo" calls it 5 times (and issue two ASCII like codes for the "é"). Was trying to figure how to loop trough that to obtain octet to build a valid utf-8 code while in the meantime I realised that in my particular case using addch() to print instead of addstr() solved my issue.